# json_query filter list of dicts which has value in a list

Tags: ansible, jmespath, json-query

I have a list of dict `mydicts=[{name: foo, data: 1}, {name: foo1, data: 3}, {name: bar, data: 2}]` and a list of names `names=[foo, foo1, mars, jonh]`

I want to create the list of dict only contains names in the list. I know if I want to select single dict I can do `jq="[?(name=='foo')]"` then `mydicts | json_query(jq)`. However I cannot make the contains version work so far. I need something like `[?(contains(names, name))]`. Can any one show me an example about how to do this?

It seems json_query correctly get the value name with contains in jq2, but it think it is a variable instead of string. I just found out there is a bug in ansible we need this `| to_json | from_json` to handle it.

In jq3, it seems it never get the value `names` I guess I need to wrap both mydicts and names into a dict and pass to jsn_query

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    mydicts:
      - name: foo
        data: 1
      - name: bar
        data: 2
    names:
      - foo
      - foo1
      - mars
      - jonh
    jq1: "[?(name == 'foo')]"
    jq2: "[?(contains(name, 'f'))]"
    jq3: "[?(contains(names, name))]"
  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: json
  - name: JMEPath test equal
    debug:
      msg: "{{mydicts | json_query(jq1)}}"
  - name: JMEPath test str contain str does not work
    debug:
      msg: "{{mydicts | json_query(jq2)}}"
  - name: JMEPath test another list contain str
    debug:
      msg: "{{mydicts | json_query(jq3)}}"
    ignore_errors: yes
```

```
TASK [JMEPath test equal] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "data": 1,
            "name": "foo"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [JMEPath test str contain str] **************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\nIn function contains(), invalid type for value: foo, expected one of: ['array', 'string'], received: \"unknown\""}
...ignoring

TASK [JMEPath test another list contain str] *****************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\nIn function contains(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array', 'string'], received: \"null\""}
...ignoring
```

For this simple example, there is a work around: using jinja filter `"{{mydicts | selectattr('name', 'in', names) | list}}"`. But I still need the json_query functionality for deep nested keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMESPath does not have visibility into the jinja2 variables in the same way that the jinja2 filters do, which is why the reference to `names` doesn't do what you are expecting: JMESPath thinks that is a field on the current-node *named* `names`, rather than a reference to that jinja2 variable

AFAIK you can either construct an artificial input structure just to make both of those pieces of data available to JMESPath (akin to `{"names": [...], "mydicts": ...}` or you can inline the `names` list into the JMESPath query:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: '{{ mydicts | json_query(jq) }}'
  vars:
    jq: '[? contains(`{{ names | to_json }}`, name) ]'
```

Comment: Function: contains, needs filter: to_json | from_json according to the manual. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"[?(contains(names, name))]. Can anyone show me an example of how to do this?"*

A: IMHO. It's not possible. The function [contains](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#contains) takes the item from the input and searches if the item contains the parameter.

```
boolean contains(array|string $subject, any $search)
```

You need a function with the same functionality but switched parameters. Hypothetically,

```
boolean in(any $search, array|string $subject)
```

which could be translated to a (hypothetical) query

```yaml
jq: "[?(in(name, names))]"
```

There is no such [function](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#built-in-functions).

---

Notes:

- `selectattr` can handle nested attributes